# iOS eBook app creator / maker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am looking for ready made ebook template for Xcode. 
So far I have found

A) Story Book iOS App Template 
http://www.binpress.com/app/story-book-ios-app-template-ipad-iphone/491/issues

b) Awesome ebook starter kit
http://www.binpress.com/app/ipad-ebook-starter-kit/681

c) Comic book ipad app 
www.binpress.com/app/comic-book-ipad-app-xcode-project/530

Wondering whether there are more options out there?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i also just ran into `AppKit` while looking for ready-to-use templates but its not free
take a look:

http://getappkit.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Mac app that has 5 templates:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/book-palette/id497704085?mt=12